# Reset a css to its initial value

Tags: css

I have an `a { color: #333 }`on a unreachable style sheet, and I need to use the following rules:

```
.entry-content a:link, a:visited {
color: #E40000 !important;
text-decoration: underline !important;
}
.entry-title a:link, a:visited {
color: #E40000 !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
}


.entry-content a:hover {
color: rgb(27, 137, 169);
text-decoration: underline !important;
}
.entry-title a:hover {
color: rgb(27, 137, 169);
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

But they are not properly working, due to the "a" element on the external style sheet.

I tried using:

```
.entry-content .entry-title a { color: inherit ; text-decoration: inherit }
```

But it's not working. I need to get rid of the "a" element.

Comment: what do you mean by "unreachable style sheet"?

Comment: Your last code line shows you setting color:inherit, etc, but then you say you want to get rid of the a element. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I used inherit to get rid of the "a" that is pre-defined on an external style sheet.